# Redefinition of generic for plot function breaks plot.formula

Tags: r, generics, plot

CRAN policies do not allow that single methods (for generic functions) which are defined in base or recommended packages are replaced. They advice package authors to replace the standard generic and use a `xxx.default` method which then calls the original standard generic.

An example from my package **papeR** is as follows:

```
## overwrite standard generic
plot <- function(x, y, ...)
    UseMethod("plot")

## per default fall back to standard generic
plot.default <- function(x, y, ...)
    graphics::plot(x, y, ...)

## now specify modified plot function for data frames
plot.data.frame <- function(x, variables = names(x), ...)
```

The complete code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/hofnerb/papeR/blob/master/R/plot.R).

For various generics such as `toLatex` this method works perfectly. Yet, the above plot method definitions break the standard `plot.formula` function:

```
library("devtools")
install_github("hofnerb/papeR")

## still works:
example(plot.formula, package="graphics")    

### But:
library("papeR")
example(plot.formula, package="graphics")
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Ozone' not found
```

I can still use

```
graphics:::plot.formula(Ozone ~ Wind, data = airquality)
```

though. Other plot functions keep working, see e.g.

```
example("plot", package = "graphics")
```

---

*Additional Information*

In my [NAMESPACE](https://github.com/hofnerb/papeR/blob/master/NAMESPACE) I have

```
importFrom("graphics", "plot", "plot.default", ...)
export(plot, plot.data.frame, ...)
S3method(plot, default)
S3method(plot, data.frame)
```

---

For a previous discussion on this topic (with a different focus) see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222368/method-dispatch-for-generic-plot-function-in-r).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a discussion and solution (define a `new_class` and use `plot.new_class`) see 
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2015q3/000463.html